CompletableFuture.allof() gets nullpointerexception
I have a structure similar to the code block below.
When I test with the same data list, sometimes it works correctly and there is no error, but sometimes it throws  nullpointerException in CompletableFuture.allOf method:
What could be the problem here?
--new edit--
async methods do not return null when I debug, but is it possible that async methods add to the completableFuture object before returning any object? so it sees the object as null ?
Thanks..
List<CompletableFuture<String>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();

for(Classx list : request.getlist()) {
    switch (list.getCases()) {
        case 1:
            completableFutures.add(asyncProcess(list));
            break;
        case 2:
            completableFutures.add(asyncProcess2(list));
            break;
    }
}
CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));


@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> asyncProcess(Classx list) {
    try{
        //..some codes
    } catch(Exception e){
        //..some codes
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(x.getX());
}


@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> asyncProcess2(Classx list) {
    try{
        //..some codes
    } catch(Exception e){
        //..some codes
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(x.getX());
}

error message is :
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1306)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1305)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.andTree(CompletableFuture.java:1303)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.java:2225)



When I change the code as follows, it throws the same error.
CompletableFuture allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFuture.size()]));

Presumably completableFutures contains a null element. Hard to say why without a [mcve].

Looking at the source code for CompletableFutre.andTree, it seems this exception is thrown when an element of the passed in array is null. There must be some additional return statement in one of your asyncProcees functions that can return null.

not even needed to look at the source code, it is clearly documented: "Throws:
NullPointerException - if the array or any of its elements are null"

When I test with the same data list, sometimes it works correctly and there is no error, but sometimes it throws nullpointerException in CompletableFuture.allOf method. Also   async methods do not return null when I debug, but is it possible that async methods add to the completableFuture object before returning any object? so it sees the object as null ?
